# Multiple outlets (4), in different rooms not working

Tags: receptacle

Two outlets in master bath, one out on back patio, and one next to front door (exterior) aren't working.  They have no power going to them so I replaced the circuit breaker but that didn't fix them.  I tested all other outlets(gfci's working and not tripped) and they were working properly. All switches and lights are working, it is just these four random outlets. One of the two in the bathroom has three wires coming into it.  I'm assuming one is for the end of a run outlet just a few feet away and the other is for the fan above the toilet (I'm assuming). The outlet on the back patio that isnt working appears to be an end of the run outlet and has only one wire coming into it.  The outlet by the front door has two lines coming into it.  I bought new outlets but seeing that none of problem outlets has power coming into the box, I'm sure that isnt my problem.

Comment: Unless the electricity cables are older than the 90s, you should have GFCI protection for all those outlets.  If the one who did the wiring was smart, they keep the GFCI protection indoors.  Do any of the outlets have small switches/buttons on them?

Comment: Have you looked for a tripped GFCI? - these things really should not all be shared, but might be anyway, as typical for old GFCI installations where the bathrooms and exterior outlets would all get hung off a single GFCI. That might be located some non-obvious place like the garage or basement, for extra fun in finding it.

Comment: It's possible all those non-functioning receptacles are normally powered by a single GFCI device, which has tripped, and which could be anywhere, even hidden. Some GFCI's have a "blank" face with just the test and reset buttons and are easy to overlook.

Comment: I’ve worked in a number of houses where the gfi for the bathroom was found in the garage or somewhere non-obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You have a GFCI that has opened...and you haven't found it yet.

One of my past home was wired the exact same way.  Bathroom outlet, exterior outlet by front door, exterior outlet on back porch, all fed by a GFCI in the garage.

Look behind things like storage or boxes in the garage.

I had a neighbor that waited for 3 days for the cable/ internet guy to show up because he had no internet.  The problem was the modem was on a circuit fed by a tripped GFCI in the garage that was behind a big storage closet.

Comment: Yep, my house has a GFCI outlet that controls a bunch of other outlets...in the *basement bathroom closet.*